# How to solve TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list?

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I am downloading data in json format and saving it into a data frame.

```
data = []
for day in range(9,10):
       request=Request('https://api..../10/'+str(day)+'/'+appId='+appID+')
       response = urlopen(request)
       arrivals = response.read()
       d = json.loads(arrivals)
       data.append(json_normalize(d['Statuses']))

data[column_names].to_csv("data.csv")
```

However the last line of this code provides an error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

It looks like `data` is a list. I tried create `data` as follows: `data = pandas.DataFrame()`, but there was also an error.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: You're missing a closing `'` somewhere. Please post realistic code.

Comment: What's in `column_names`? I'm guessing a list?

Comment: @juanchopanza: This is the realistic code. I cannot post real request for security reason. All other things are copy-paste from my code. By the way the code works without "append" within for loop.

Comment: @David Ehrmann: column_names=['aaa','bbb']

Comment: BS, you just fixed your code.

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate all the results from the different requests?

Comment: @Anand S Kumar: Right, but the response has always same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` is a list, as you define it at the start - `data = []` - Hence when you trying to access them using another list `column_names` , you get the error you are getting.

If you are trying to concatenate the different dataframes you get from the different requests, you should use [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) on `data` to concatenate all the dataframes from the list into a single dataframe, before accessing its columns and using [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) on it. Example -

```
data[column_names].to_csv("data.csv")
```

Should be changed to -

```
pd.concat(data)[column_names].to_csv("data.csv")
```